Operador OR no funciona Javascript
estoy trabajando en unos filtros de busqueda con ajax, pero mi problema es cuando trato de usar el operador OR, no se si lo estoy usando mal pero les agradezco su ayuda y correciones.
he aqui el codigo:


function busqueda(){
        var tipoParte = $("#tipoRef").find(":selected").val();
        var marcas = $("#marcas").find(":selected").val();
        var version = $("#versionescat").find(":selected").val();
        var modelo = $("#modelocat").find(":selected").val();
        if(tipoParte == 0){
            if (marcas == 0 || version == 0 || modelo == 0){
                alert("Debes elegir un tipo de Refacción");
            } else {
                alert("comprobacion correcta");
            }
        }

    }
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <select id="tipoRef">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Tipo de Refacción</option>
                <option value="1">Motores</option>
                <option value="2">Transmisiones</option>
                <option value="3">Cabezas</option>
                <option value="4">Cigueñales</option>
                <option value="5">Bielas</option>
            </select>
        <select id="marcas">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecionar marca</option>
        <option value="1">Nissan</option>
        </select>
    <select id="versionescat">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccionar version</option>
        <option value="1">Tsuru</option>
    </select>
    <select id="modelocat">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccionar modelo</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
    </select>
            <input type="button" name="Buscar" value="Buscar" onclick="busqueda()">



el caso es que necesito comprobar si marcas = 0 o si version = 0 o si modelo = 0. me de una alerta...Notese que donde va la alerta va mas codigo, pero no logro hacer funcionar ese operador, y por alguna razon me lo detecta como &&

y al reves?  onda if ( 0 !==tal_cosa && 0!== tal_otra) si necesitas todas las variables distintas de cero puede que sea mas claro, si cada variable en 0 hace o valida una cosa diferente pones un flag de "valido=true" y cada que no pase el if lo pone a false, luego si valido es false ( por x razon ) mostras alerta, si valido = true procesas el form

A mí me funciona bien, porque dices que no funciona el or ??

Quizá el if previo (tipoParte == 0) no se está cumpliendo

el (tipoParte == 0) si se cumple, mi problema es que siendo un OR yo esperaria que si se cumple una de las tres condiciones se ejecute mi codigo cosa que no está funcionando pues debo tener los esos tres campos en valores diferentes a 0 para que se ejecute el segundo codigo

Pero entonces lo que estás buscando es que cuando los 3 sean "0" entonces se lance el error... La lógica de tu if está invertida.

La alerta funciona tal como está codificado. Creo que tu explicación es poco clara, pues parece coincidir con la explicación también. Por qué no explicas en lenguaje sencillo cuándo debe aparecer la alerta y cuándo no. No con tecnicismos, sino como si se lo explicaras a un niño de 5 años.

Según entiendo tu caso, quieres que la condicional if (marcas == 0 || version == 0 || modelo == 0) se cumpla si el usuario selecciona al menos uno de los tres criterios (marca, version o modelo).
Tu condicional actual se traduce a: ai alguno de los criterios está vacío, lanza el error. Por ende, el usuario debe seleccionar todos los criterios.
Si quieres que alert("comprobacion correcta") se ejecute cuando se selecciona al menos uno de esos tres criterios, tu condicional debería ser
if (marcas != 0 || version != 0 || modelo != 0) {
  alert("comprobacion correcta");
} else {
  alert("Debes elegir un tipo de Refacción");
}

O incluso
if (marcas == 0 && version == 0 && modelo == 0) {
  alert("Debes elegir un tipo de Refacción");
} else {
  alert("comprobacion correcta");
}

Con esto, si al menos uno de los tres criterios es diferente de 0, o sea, que el usuario seleccionó una opción, entra en la condicional.

Por favor, explica con lenguaje natural si tu necesidad no es exactamente como la expliqué en mi respuesta y la puedo editar para dar una código adecuado. Aunque según entendí en los comentarios, esto es lo que necesitas.

if(tipoParte == 0){ // #1
    if (marcas == 0 || version == 0 || modelo == 0){
         alert("Debes elegir un tipo de Refacción");
    } else {
         alert("comprobacion correcta");
            }
    }

En la condición #1, la verificación utilizada considera únicamente si el tipoParte es igual a cero. Si es cero, caerá en la segunda condición que utiliza el operador OR, el cual considera que al menos UNO de los campos marcas, versión o modelo es igual a CERO.
El uso del operador OR en los campos marcas, versión, modelo significa que si los valores son 1, 1 y 0, el operador solo considerará el cero. Si todos los campos comienzan con cero, mostrará el mensaje *alert("Debes elegir un tipo de Refacción");* o al menos 1 será verdadero. Y si todos son 1, mostrará el mensaje alert("comprobación correcta"); que será falso.

Todo está correcto en lo que respecta al operador "OR".

Observa la tabla de los operadores lógicos.



A
B
A AND B
A NAND B
A OR B
A XOR B
NOT A




false
false
false
true
false
false
true


false
true
false
true
true
true
true


true
false
false
true
true
true
false


true
true
true
false
true
false
false



Una adaptación a tu código es usar el operador de negación ! con él, lo que invertirá el valor booleano de la expresión, lo que es true se convertirá en false y false se convertirá en true. El operador OR evalúa si al menos una de las expresiones es true.


tipoParte = 0


marcas =   1
version = 0
modelo =  0


if(tipoParte == 0){
        if (!(marcas == 0 || version == 0 || modelo == 0)){
            alert("Debes elegir un tipo de Refacción");
        } else {
            alert("comprobacion correcta");
        }
    

}



Al aplicar el operador && AND, devuelve verdadero si ambos operandos son verdaderos.
La lógica del operador AND tendrá el mismo resultado que la negación del operador OR.
Cuando se utiliza el OR, este operador considerará si existe solo uno de los campos que contenga cero, será true, y si todos los campos son mayores que cero, será false.


tipoParte = 0

marcas =  1 //false
version = 1 //false
modelo =  1 //false

 if(tipoParte == 0){
            if (marcas == 0 || version == 0 || modelo == 0){
                alert("Debes elegir un tipo de Refacción");
            } else {
                alert("comprobacion correcta");
            }
        }



